# Why implicit linking to DLL needs a lib file on Windows

Tags: dll, linker, shared-libraries

On Linux platforms you need only the .so file when you want to implicitly link to it.
Why Microsoft developed the approach where you need a .lib file also. Doesn't the DLL contain all the information for the linker to be able to link to it?

From my experience the "Windows way" is more clumsy and creates problems when you want to mix different compilers and linkers.